# Display functions within the file along with the filename

Tags: grep

I have some bunch of c files, and i would like to collect the functions declarations within all the files, i did achieved this by the following command:

cat *.c | grep -E "^\w" | sed 's/$/;/'

Here comes the real problem, i would like to extend this to print the file name before the function, the end output should be of the format as mentioned below:

**Function< tab space> void xxx_func()**

Thanks in advance.

Source:
http://jules.dourlens.com/extracting-c-function-prototype/#comment-540

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without **cat**

`grep -h function *.c | sed "s/^.*\(function\)\s\+\(.*\)$/\1\t\2;/"`